# Explanation for finding number of columns in a 2d array

Tags: arrays

Answer : for example

```
int arr[3][3] = {{0,1,20}, {4,5,6}, {8,9,10}};
```

0 1 20
4 5 6
8 9 10

```
int rows = arr.length;
int columns= arr[0].length;
```

2d array is nothing but array having arrays inside.
we get number of rows by just using length function to outer array (no. of inner arrays it has).
i.e, number of inner arrays
{0,1,20}, {4,5,6}, {8,9,10}

we get number of columns by length of elements in the inner array.
i.e, length of any inner {0,1,20} which is 3

Answer (score 0):

Answer : for example

int arr[3][3] = {{0,1,20}, {4,5,6}, {8,9,10}};

0 1 20 4 5 6 8 9 10

int rows = arr.length; int columns= arr[0].length;

2d array is nothing but array having arrays inside. we get number of rows by just using length function to outer array (no. of inner arrays it has). i.e, number of inner arrays {0,1,20}, {4,5,6}, {8,9,10}

we get number of columns by length of elements in the inner array. i.e, length of any inner {0,1,20} which is 3